# Is it alright to sign different apps using different keys in the same Google Play developer account

Tags: android-keystore

I have developed some apps for a client. The client has a publisher account on Google Play. All of these are signed using the same key.

Now, can I publish a new app withe a new keystore in the same GooglePlay account for the client? So, effectively the same developer account would have apps with different keys. Can this lead to any problems later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that there is no problem in doing this.